# Group_by rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am searching for getting the count of grouped elements in rails by group_by `User.all.group_by{ |a| a.created_at.year }`  is there any ways to get count out of this as like group in rails

Comment: How is your expected output? What is your DBMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below queries

1)

```
User.all.group("date_part('year', created_at)").count
```

2)

```
User.all.group("DATE_TRUNC('year', created_at)").count
```

3)

```
User.group("TO_CHAR(created_at, 'Month YYYY')").count
```

4)

```
User.all.group('(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at))::integer').count
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User.all.group_by{|a| a.created_at.year}.each_with_object({}){|(k,v),res| res[k]=v.size}
```

You can achieve the same using `group`:

```
User.all.group("YEAR(created_at)").count
```

Example output (`year => number of users`):

```
{2017=>18, 2018=>14}
```

Comment: Getting this error, ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function year(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
 (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, YEAR(created_at) AS year_created_at FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL GROUP BY YEAR(created_at)

Comment: `DATE_PART('year', created_at)`

Comment: As @Iceman mentioned, you should use `date_part`. `year` comes from MySQL, not PostgreSQL (you have not mentioned which database you use).

Comment: I am using postgreSQL